# Updates/inserts not working in postgres trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have following function and trigger-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copyX() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN        
WITH    
    updates (id) AS (
    UPDATE tbl_history
    SET price=0
    FROM tbl
    WHERE tbl.id = tbl_history.id
        AND tbl_history.price=1
    RETURNING tbl_history.id
   )
   INSERT INTO tbl_history 
   SELECT id,1 FROM tbl;

    RETURN new;
    
   END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;


create  TRIGGER T_X
  AFTER INSERT ON TBL
  FOR EACH ROW
  execute procedure function_copyX();
```

So, whenever I am inserting any record in TBL, I expect inserts/updates in the TBL_HISTORY but this does not work in trigger function.
But if I execute this 'WITH code' separately it works.
What could be the issue? please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below modification worked!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copyX() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    
WITH    
    updates (id) AS (
    UPDATE tbl_history
    SET price=0   WHERE id =NEW.id AND price=1
    RETURNING id
   )
   INSERT INTO tbl_history (id,price) values   (NEW.id,1);

    RETURN new;
    
   END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

create  TRIGGER T_X
  AFTER INSERT ON TBL
  FOR EACH ROW
  execute procedure function_copyX();
```